# Is there a good way to disable all plugins in vim for a single file?

Tags: vim, plugins

I am working on a huge file so vim is being pretty laggy. I don't need all the plugins if it is going to be this slow. Is there a good way to disable all plugins for just one file?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most plugins don't interfere with this; they are only slow when they are invoked via their command or mapping. It's mostly syntax highlighting and some `:autocmds`. You can turn that off via

```
:syntax off
:set eventignore=all
```

Also, have a look at the [LargeFile plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1506) for a "just works" solution; it automatically detects such files and reconfigures Vim as best as possible.

Comment: Thanks!  Note for others: to re-enable you just to `set eventignore=`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, however the plugins doesn't really work since it doesn't seem to call `:set eventignore=all` which is the only command that makes vim smooth with large files